# TouchMoveEvent gets for just one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have grid out of divs and want to color them while moving my finger over them.

If I use the `touchmove` event only the first div is colored:

```
        $("#grid .divCell").each(function () {
            $(this).bind("touchmove", function (e) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "red");
            });
        });
```

Suggestions?

/edit

Razor view:

```
<div id="grid">        
    <div class="divTable">
        @for(var i = 0; i<=15; i++) {
        <div class="divRow">
            @for(var e = 0; e<=15; e++) {
            <div class="divCell" onclick="set(@(17 * i), @(17 * e));">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            }
        </div>
        }
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the markup?

Comment: sorry, what do you need?

Comment: Okay if this may help you :)

Comment: Is `set()` a javascript function you created?

Comment: Have you tried using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of `.bind()`? Try doing this: `$('#grid .divCell').on('touchmove', function(){});` or `$('#grid').delegate('.divCell','touchmove', function(){});`